# Gamification Achievement System

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a gamification web app im working on . At the moment , users can see the badges they have if they go to their profile.

The badges are stored in a database along with the user that has earned it.

Does anyone know a way that I can make a notification appear when the user logs in to inform them that they have earned a new badge?

Comment: A simple boolean flag on the badge table should be sufficient. When the user logs in, check the flag for which badges haven't been notified, and display them.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by storing the date when the user logged in for the last time and comparing it with the date when the badge was earned.

**UPDATE**

You could also add a "seen" column to the table user_badge, so when the user visits his own profile, you mark all the non-seen badges as seen.